# How to ignore a 404 error in an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I have an AJAX call to retrieve some data in JSON format. And that data I want to use for something. However, if there is no data, I want something else to happen. I have this function which works exactly how I want it to:

```
var config = {
      type: "GET",
      url: /my/url/,
      success: function(context) { do_something(context); },
      error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions, thrownError) { if (xhr.status == 404){do_something_else()}}
    };
    $.ajax(config);
```

However, in the console I still get:

> 404 NOT FOUND

How can I ignore/catch that error, I thought this is being done with the `error:...` line?

**EDIT**

I tried this

```
var config = {
          type: "GET",
          url: /my/url/
        }
        $.ajax(config);

    $( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
      if (settings.url === /my/url/){
        if (xhr.status == 404){
          do_something_else();
        }
        else if (xhr.status == 200){
          do_something();
        }    
      }
});
```

Comment: The error is still happening, it's just that Javascript is processing the error data. I don't think you can do anything about console logs.

Comment: `do_something_else()` is being called, why do you care what the console says?

Comment: cause an error should not show up.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the HTTP response code and change property `success` to `complete` in the jQuery ajax call, so that the handler is executed when the request is done no matter the server response. You know the server response (it always works). The HTML should still be available in the jQuery complete handler.

Comment: yes try changing ajax success method to ajax complete method, you will still have your response html

Comment: I tried that (I updated my code) it still throws the error